# Given ClearCase stream name, how to get tag of local dynamic view?

Tags: view, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I already know a non-elegant solution:

1. get list of all views of stream with `cleartool lsstream -l`
2. find the view with `Server host: ***` equal to machine name by running `cleartool lsview -l` for all these views

It might be quite slow, because there are many views...

Is there a faster alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reverse your sequence and:

- first [list all views for a specific hostname](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsview.htm?lang=en): without the `-l` option, it is quite fast

  ```
  cleartool lsview -host <hostname> -quick
  ```
- intersect that list with the views listed by `cleartool lsstream -l`.

Comment: `cleartool lsview -host %computername%` is very slow (hangs for at least 5 minutes, in my case)

Comment: `cleartool lsview -host %computername% -quick` does not output anything

Comment: Which version of ClearCase are you using? What OS are you using for your  ClearCase client? For your ClearCase server? Are you in the right region?

Comment: though, the above command actually works, with lower-cased computer name

Comment: also, the * in `cleartool lsview -host $host -quick` output indicates **dynamic** view

Comment: @my_stk_oflw_account yes, at least for started dynamic views.